# Div element is only loading correctly after clicks

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, primeng

I am having a bit of trouble when loading dynamic divs on Angular. I have made a button which adds new divs on each click on a specific area. But the problem happens once I have added them, as they are shown incorrectly:

[image: Imagem 1]

The editor and the calendar (Both are made by PrimeNG) are not shown after I add such div, as it shows on the picture above. But after I click twice on the text box (marked as red in the picture below), the components load up.

[image: Imagem 2]

Here is the HTML code I am using to show that.

```
<div class="ui-g-9" style="border: 2px solid #c8c8c8; border-radius: 5px;">
        <section class="card" style="display: flex; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: unset;">
                <div *ngFor="let disparaEmail of disparaEmails" class="ui-g-4" style="margin-right: 10px; border: 1px solid #c8c8c8; border-radius: 5px; min-width: 466.828px;">

                    <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700">Assunto:</p>
                    <textarea pInputTextarea [rows]="2" [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.assuntoEmail" style="width: 100%; resize:unset; font-size: 18px;"></textarea>

                    <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700">Tipo de Aviso:</p>
                    <p-editor [style]="{'height':'300px'}" [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.msgEmail"></p-editor>

                    <p class="titulo-campo font1 fw700">Data:</p>
                    <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="disparaEmail.dataEmail" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" showButtonBar="true" [locale]="br" [monthNavigator]="true"
                        [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="2018:2050"></p-calendar>

                </div>
        </section>
</div>

 <div style="display: inline-grid;">
        <i class="fa fa-plus botoes-chamada" (click)="addAviso()" style="color: #819049; padding:30px; margin-bottom: 10px;" pTooltip="Adicionar um tipo de aviso."></i>
        <i class="fa fa-minus botoes-chamada" (click)="deletaAviso()" style="color: #905149; padding:10px;" pTooltip="Remover o último tipo de aviso inserido."></i>
 </div>
```

Here is the TS part:

```
addAviso(){
    this.disparaEmails.push(new EmailDispara());
}

deletaAviso(){
    if (this.disparaEmails.length > 1){
        this.disparaEmails.splice(this.disparaEmails.length - 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any Angular code in your Angular question.

Comment: Ohhh! Sorry about that! Should I put in the TypeScript part, or is it okay @isherwood?

Comment: can you add the ts file and if possible simulate the issue in http://stackblitz.com

Comment: Of course. How can we troubleshoot your app without it? In particular, `addAviso()` and `deletaAviso()`, but also anything else relevant.

Comment: There! I have added the TS part, I am going to share the stackblitz simulation in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably the common problem of not properly detecting changes. Add [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef) injection into your component:

```
constructor (..., changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

and invoke `detectChanges` after adding/removing:

```
addAviso(){
    this.disparaEmails.push(new EmailDispara());
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges(); // <- this line here
}
```

Comment: That did the right trick! I shall remember this change detector, thanks for that!